# Problem with Two Datasets in the same layout in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

IN my SSRS project, I created two datasets that I want to use in the same layout.

In my layout, I added two tables. I drag columns from one dataset to one table, and they are all fine.

Then I drag columns from the 2nd dataset (same column names as those in the first dataset) to the 2nd table, and it becomes First(....) , as if it thinks I want only the first row of that dataset.

Why does it automatically add first(...) and more importantly,how do I refer to the same column names from different datasets in the same layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random thoughts:

Where are the tables? In the body, header or footer?

Have you bound each table to the dataset (you can't mix and match columns in one table)?
That is, did you set one table up then copy/paste it?

I have reports with many tables each with a different data set with overlapping column names.